# is $m^*(\mathbb{R})=\infty$?

Tags: measure-theory

By definition: $$m^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|I_n|:E\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n\right\}$$

So in the case of $\mathbb{R}$ an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$ itself but if we take $I_n=(r_n-\varepsilon, r_n+\varepsilon)$ where $r_n\in \mathbb{R}$ then:

$$m^*(\mathbb{R})=\inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|I_n|\right\}=\inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|r_n+\varepsilon-r_n+\varepsilon|\right\}=\inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|2\varepsilon|\right\}=0$$

Which is wrong, may as we can not sum up as $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable?

Comment: Why is $\inf\left\{\sum_{n\ge 1}2\epsilon\right\}=0$?

Comment: @d.k.o. correct it is true for any $\varepsilon>0$ so it can be finite or infinite

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is uncountable, so when you write "where $r_n \in \mathbb R$" you get into trouble.

Comment: @d.k.o. sec, this is true for any $\varepsilon>0$ so it true also for $\frac{1}{n}$ and as $n\to \infty $ this how we prove that the measure of a singleton is $0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $(-x,x)\subset\mathbb{R}$, $m^{*}(\mathbb{R})\ge m^{*}(-x,x)=2x$ for any $x>0$.

Answer (score 2):

For **every** sequence $\left(I_{n}\right)_{n}$ of intervals with $\mathbb{R}\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}$
it is true that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|I_{n}\right|=\infty$ provided
the $\left|I_{n}\right|$ stands for the length of interval $I_{n}$.

So $\left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|I_{n}\right|:\mathbb{R}\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}\right\} $
only contains one element which is $\infty$.

Then: $$m^*(\mathbb R)=\inf\left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|I_{n}\right|:\mathbb{R}\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}\right\} =\inf\left\{ \infty\right\} =\infty$$